# WIX: Show page if specific feature is selected

Tags: wix

I created msi installer and this installer contains 2 features for installing.

```
<Feature Id="StandaloneFeature"
         Title="$(var.StandaloneName)"
         Description ="$(var.StandaloneName)"
         Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="xxx"/>      
  <ComponentRef Id="xxx"/>
</Feature>    
<Feature Id="PreCheckerFeature"
         Title="$(var.PrecheckerName)"
         Description="Prerequisites Checker sets system for launching automation scripts."
         Level="2">
  <Condition Level="0">INSTALLLEVEL=3</Condition>
        <ComponentRef Id="xxx"/>
</Feature>
```

Also I have PrcSettingsDlg specific dialog which need show if `Feature Id="PreCheckerFeature"`is selected in the SelectionTree control on the CustomizeDlg. I tried to use
 `<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="PrcSettingsDlg" Order="3" ><![CDATA[MsiSelectionTreeSelectedCost ="986"]]></Publish>` and
 `<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="PrcSettingsDlg" Order="3" ><![CDATA[MsiSelectionTreeSelectedFeature ="PreCheckerFeature"]]></Publish>` but it doesn't work.
Could you help me understand how I can create condition for showing page in the UI?

**UPD**
I found solution

```
<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="PrcSettingsDlg" Order="3" ><![CDATA[&PreCheckerFeature = 3]]></Publish>          
<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="4"><![CDATA[&PreCheckerFeature <> 3]]></Publish>
```

Maybe it will help somebody.

Comment: Your update helped me, especially after finding the meaning of the condition in: https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax/